# Singapore - Working on a tourist visa

Tags: india, tourist-visas, singapore, work

I am from India and will be visiting Singapore for social visit/tourism.
My employer has given me pto but asked me to take my work laptop with me in case the need arise for me to log in and work.

Can I do this on a tourist visa?

Comment: You may want to push back by saying "When I cross a border with a work laptop, the customs/immigration folks may want me to unlock my laptop so that they can look inside (for contraband information like child porn or whatever)".  Once you give up control of that laptop, everything proprietary on it should be considered compromised.  I've worked for two companies where you weren't allowed to take company laptops across international borders except with explicit permission.

Comment: Flydog, working conditions are strenuous in India, for better or worse. Unfortunately if OP "pushed back" in that way to Employer, Employer would giggle, fire them, and say "Next, who wants PTO?"

Comment: "pto" is "Prepaid Ticket Orders"?

Answer (score 17):

Legally, yes you need a work visa, even for working remotely.

In practice, no one is going to come and check, if you occasionally login in to your work laptop.

If you don't want to, push back to your employer saying that its not legal to work while in tourist visa and you are not willing to take that risk.

Comment: Wait, are you saying that you need a work visa in order to stay just a few days (the length of a tourist visa) and carry out work for which you are paid and taxed in _another_ country? Can you give some references to support that? It seems really strange given that you are not in any way actually part of the workforce of the host country. Surely "work" is defined as "being paid by a local entity" in this context, isn't it?